# Time difference between repeated states

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am a beginner with python, and so my questions could come across as trivial. I would appreciate your support or any leads to my problem.

Problem:

There are about 10 different states; A order moves across different states and a time stamp is generated when the state ends. For example below, There are four states A, B, C, D.

```
A 10 AM
B  1 PM
C  4 Pm
D  5 PM
Time spent in B = 1PM -10AM = 3.
```

Check this out too, please. How I envision the input and output to be -Please check this file 'Sampleinputoutput' here -drive.google.com/open?id=15lBHI-TA0zLWfYcjb54hJkxjn0xv-XWx;

Some times the same state can occur multiple times. Hence, we need a variable to store the time difference value for a single state

Below the raw data csv and my code so far.There are multiple orders for which this calculation needs to be performed. however, for simplicity, I have data for just one order now.

Sample data:

```
   Order   States  modified_at
    1   Resolved    2018-06-18T15:05:52.2460000
    1   Edited      2018-05-24T21:44:07.9030000
        Pending PO Creation 2018-06-06T19:52:51.5990000
    1   Assigned    2018-05-24T17:46:03.2090000
    1   Edited      2018-06-04T15:02:57.5130000
    1   Draft       2018-05-24T17:45:07.9960000
    1   PO Placed   2018-06-06T20:49:37.6540000
    1   Edited      2018-06-04T11:18:13.9830000
    1   Edited      2018-05-24T17:45:39.4680000
    1   Pending Approval    2018-05-24T21:48:23.9180000
    1   Edited      2018-06-06T21:00:19.6350000
    1   Submitted   2018-05-24T21:44:37.8830000
    1   Edited      2018-05-30T11:19:36.5460000
    1   Edited      2018-05-25T11:16:07.9690000
    1   Edited      2018-05-24T21:43:35.0770000
    1   Assigned    2018-06-07T18:39:00.2580000
    1   Pending Review  2018-05-24T17:45:10.5980000
    1   Pending PO Submission   2018-06-06T14:16:26.6580000
```

Code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

fileName = "SamplePR.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(fileName, delimiter=',')

df['modified_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df.modified_at)

df = df.sort_values(by='modified_at')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df1  = df[:-1]
df2 = df[1:]

dfm1 = df1['modified_at']
dfm2 = df2['modified_at']

dfm1 = dfm1.reset_index(drop=True)
dfm2 = dfm2.reset_index(drop=True)

for i in range(len(df)-1):
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dfm1[i]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ends  = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dfm2[i]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
diff = relativedelta(ends, start)
print (diff)
```

So far, I tried to sort the list by time and then calculate the difference between 2 states.

I would really appreciate if someone can help with logic or point in the right direction.

Comment: For multiple occurrence of `States`, do you want the difference between the `min` and `max` dates?

Comment: Thanks for the response,

Comment: Thanks for the response, The idea is to get the sum of each of the state occurences.